# Ocaml- syntax error during a pattern-matching

Tags: ocaml

Here is my code :

```
type mass    = Inf | P of int


let som = fun 
|Inf _ | _ Inf -> Inf
| (P a) (P b) -> P (a+b)
```

I get the following error :

```
line 5, characters 0-1:
Error: Syntax error
```

I don't understand at all how I can get a syntax error here. I tried to replace the fun by : match a b with yet I still get the same syntax.

I also tried to put some : ";" yet it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These patterns:

```
Inf _
_ Inf
```

don't make sense in OCaml. Both of them consist of one pattern followed directly by another. (The `Inf` pattern matches the `Inf` constuctor, and `_` is a wild-card that matches anything.)
But there is no pattern in OCaml that consists of one pattern followed by another.

The same is true of this pattern:

```
(P a) (P b)
```

If these patterns did have a meaning, they would seem to match function applications. But a pattern can't pull apart a function application, it can only pull apart data constructors (lists, tuples, etc.).

What is an example OCaml value that you would expect this pattern to match?

**Update**

You seem to be saying that the value `P 2, P 3` should match this second pattern. The value `P 2, P 3` in OCaml is a tuple. It will match this pattern:

```
(P a), (P b)
```

Note that the comma is required. The comma is the constructor that creates a tuple.

**Update 2**

Well, the other mistake is that the `fun` keyword allows only a single pattern. For multiple patterns you need to use the `function` keyword. Here is a correct version of your function (assuming that you want it to handle pairs of values of type `mass`).

```
type mass = Inf | P of int

let som = function 
|Inf, _ | _, Inf -> Inf
| (P a), (P b) -> P (a+b)
```

**Update 3**

It's more idiomatic in OCaml to have curried functions. It strikes me that this could be the reason you wanted to have adjacent patterns. To get a curried version of `som` you need to use an explicit `match`. Neither `fun` nor `function` is quite flexible enough.

It would look like this:

```
let som x y =
    match x, y with
    | Inf, _ | _, Inf -> Inf
    | P a, P b -> P (a + b)
```